# How to Search User and Page name simultaneously using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to perform a search operation that returns list of Users and Pages from Facebook.

I am using Graph API but it does not allow me do so.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search/?q=shakira&type=user&access_token={access_token}
```

API allows only 1 parameter with `type={type}`.

How i can specify both in Graph API?

Comment: You can't because it is impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to search for two types at once. You need to make two different calls with `type=user` and `type=page`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

You can use Batch Requests to make it faster though: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests